# Getting an Error Code: 0 in only IE for javascript file

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, cross-browser

Im using a Drupal 7.22 installation for my website.

I keep getting an error in IE for one of my JS files.

The error in IE states

```
 Line: 32 
 Error: Not implemented
```

[image]

This issue only occurs in IE 9 and older and only in Internet Explorer.  Chrome, FireFox, ect work without any problem.

Comment: Are you using IE on compatibility mode? Are you accessing the URL through an intranet instead of by IP?

Comment: Even in Compatibility mode the error still occurs.  Both Testing(intranet) and Production (internet) are both showing the same issue and error(code:0)

Comment: Try changing it to `var self = $(this);` then :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`self`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.self) is a global variable an alias for `window`.  You cannot change the value of the `window` variable.

You need to use `var` to make it a local variable:

```
var self = jQuery(this);
```

P.S. You should use `var` for every variable, you don't want to start creating global variables.

Comment: This kind of worked.  It fixed the error issue but the rendering is still screwed up.  BUT again only in IE.

Comment: I have made a new page with the new problem.  Would you take a look at it and see if you can think of anything. the URL is 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17173548/javascript-not-rendering-out-like-it-should-only-in-ie9-and-before

thanks